# How to pass in a parameter for a class set property (not class declaration)

Tags: c#, class, properties, parameters, set

**Background:**

I am making a c# 4.0 class for re-use so I can send one parameter to most methods of my program and pass a ‘Connections’ object that can hold things like:

- ConnectionStrings
- DbConnection (i.e. OleDbConnection or SQLConnection)
- DataReader (i.e. OleDbDataReader or SQLDataReader)

The reasoning is that I will eventually upgrade to SQL Server and don’t want to change my method parameters or code so much.  Methods often have to call a quick query here and there from the same database.

**Question:**

How do I properly setup (and call) the right-hand side of the DRMDbConnection ‘set’ parameter for DbType (now hard-coded as integer 1) in the method below at line:

```
set { drmDbConnection = SetDRMDbConnection(1); }
```

**Sample Code:**

```
public class Connections
{

public string DRMDbConnectionString { get; set; }
private object drmDbConnection;

public object DRMDbConnection
{
  get { return drmDbConnection; }
  set { drmDbConnection = SetDRMDbConnection(1); }
}

private object SetDRMDbConnection(int DbType)
{
  if (DbType == 1)
    return new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
  else
    return new SqlConnection();
}
```

}

**EDITED Oct 31**

I updated the class code to use the recommended IDbConnection, IDbCommand and IDataReader.  Note: without a change to the SQL Server connection string you will recieve an error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."  Thus add this to connection string: "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

**Updated Class code**

```
public class Connections
// reusuable object to hold all database Connections and a convenient DataReader and Command object.
// Its purpose is to also be able to handle your choice of database connection, i.e. OleDb or SQL Server.
{
public string DRMConnectionString { get; set; }
public IDbConnection DRMConnection;

public IDbCommand DRMCommand
{
  get { return DRMConnection.CreateCommand(); }
  set { }
}

public int DRMConnectionType
// must be called to setup database connection and command.  The connectionstring must be previously set.
{
  set
  {
    if (value == 1)
      DRMConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(DRMConnectionString);
    else
      DRMConnection = new SqlConnection(DRMConnectionString);
  }
}

public void CloseConnections()
{
  if (DRMCommand != null)
    DRMCommand.Dispose();

  if ((DRMConnection != null) && (DRMConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed))
    DRMConnection.Close();
}
}
```

**CALLING CODE**

```
var conn = new Connections();
conn.DRMConnectionString = "my connection string";
conn.DRMConnectionType = 2;
conn.DRMConnection.Open();
try
{
  using (var cmd = conn.DRMCommand)
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (rdr.Read())      
      {
         CallSubMethodThatAlsoOpensDataReader(conn);  
      } 
    } 
  }
}
finally
{
  conn.CloseConnections();
} 


CallSubMethodThatAlsoOpensDataReader(Connections Conn)
{
  using (var cmd = Conn.DRMCommand)
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable";
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())  // Error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
    {
       ; // do stuff
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work as follows:

```
public IDbConnection DRMDbConnection // Note the change of the type
{
    get { return drmDbConnection; }
}
public int DrmDbConnectionType
{
    set {
        if (vale== 1)
            drmDbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        else
            drmDbConnection = new SqlConnection();
    }
}
```

> The reasoning is that I will eventually upgrade to SQL Server and don’t want to change my method parameters or code so much.

I think this is the key issue that you are trying to solve. Rather than programming to the specific class, program to an interface. Specifically, using [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx) instead of `SqlConnection` or `OleDbConnection` would let you hide the exact type better than encapsulating it in the `DRMDbConnection`.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea -now implementing IDBConnection etc.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight : I have edited the question to show the revised class code and calling code that uses IDbConnection etc. I use a local IDataReader but am not sure if I need to dispose of the IDbCommand in every method where I re-use it in an using clause just like I do for the IDataReader...

Comment: @user610064 The easiest thing is to move the `CreateCommand()` call outside of the `DRMDbConnectionType` setter, and into the getter of the `DRMCommand`. Then you could add `using (var cmd = conn.DRMCommand)`, open the command and set its text inside the `using` block. This will make your code thread-safe.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight : I have edited the question to show the solution but receive an error using SQL Server but not MS Access (OleDB). Error occurs in submethod when opening IDataReader.  Error is: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: @user610064 Is this your real code? The `CloseConnections` method is unnecessary; `DRMDataReader` is never assigned, and `DRMConnection` should be private, not public. Are you using this concurrently?

Comment: @dashblinkenlight No I am not using this code - eventually might after it is cleaned up.  I found the error was because of something I need to add to the connection string for SQL server "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;".   I think I would 'feel' safer if I manually closed the connection at least in a try finally..

Comment: @dashblinkenlight If I set DRMConnection to private the error when opening a connection will be "...is inaccessible due to its protection level".  Even though others are 'supposed' to close their readers, commands etc does not mean that they will or they will be closed in a timely fashion, so I think it is a good idea to manually close them.  <Cleaned up DataReader out of class>

Comment: @user610064 Got it. I did not see the `Open()` call on the connection. If you are managing the connection's state manually, though, your `Connections` class is essentially reduced to a factory encapsulating an RDBMS-specific connection string. I think this is a good approach, though: I would make my `Connections` class as simple as possible.

Comment: I wonder if there are any issues with using this one open connection for a period of say 5 minutes?  There would be threading issues or transaction issues if the connection gets closed I believe but this will probably run only on our internal SQL server in a windows service and that would seem unlikely.

Comment: @user610064 Do you have jobs that run for five minutes?.. Generally, it should not be a problem to open and close connections as frequently as you wish, with no performance penalty, because DB connections are pooled in .NET.

Comment: I have one job that runs longer that 5 minutes but it is to MS Access on nework file server and the connection occurs on the client.  I do know about connection pooling but was wondering theoretically how long this DRMConnection could/should stay open.  I will rest easy then.

Comment: @user610064 I do not know how long a connection could stay open, but I usually close the connection as soon as I finish with it. I would not take my answer as a definitive, though: I think a question about "longevity" of `IDbConnection` would make a legitimate standalone question.

Answer (score 1):

Property getter/setters cannot take parameters. You will need to implement this as method.

Comment: +1 and probably a property that returns "object" but needs an integer as parameter...shouldn't be a property at all.